# Bootstrap carousel to move by one thumbnail on next / prev

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jcarousel

I'm trying to implement Twitter Bootstrap carousel thumbnail way, so there are gallery of thumbnails user can slide next and prev. Basically, it is this solution: http://bootply.com/64680

But this moves sets of thumbnails, and I would like to have more control, to move by 1 thumbnail, ideally optional number of thumbnail.

There is one solution I found here that does what I want jsfiddle.net/masterbee/dGTnu/6/embedded/result/

but it seems it does not work with jQuery 1.8.3.

Anyone tried this with success ?

Answer (score 1):

Add a event listener on the thumbnail once you click it, trigger an event ( look on the next / prev events on the slider ) determine where you are located i.e. 3rd slide and clicked the 2nd then need to trigger prev method / clicked 4th then need to trigger next method.

Thats the way i will handle this.